# Unable to return an object's value from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, xmlhttprequest

I have a function which attempts to capture a return value from a calling function in the following manner:

```
var select = xhrRetrieve(projID);
```

Here is an example of the xhrRetrieve function:

```
function xhrRetrieve(projID) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

                return obj.select.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    var url = "ajax.cgi";
    var data = "action=retrieve-opp&proj-id=" + projID;

    xhr.open("POST",url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);

}
```

I am using jQuery in conjunction with straight JavaScript. Whenever I attempt to get the value of obj.select using:

```
var select = xhrRetrieve(projID);
```

Select always comes back `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function doesn't return anything
2. The moment you call your function, the (not currently present) return value is being assigned to `select`. At the same moment, your ajax request is being fired, which takes time to complete; the callback function will not be called until the ajax request has completed (and succeeded).

This should work:

```
function doStuffWithTheAjaxResponse(select) {
   // do stuff
}

function xhrRetrieve(projID) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

                doStuffWithTheAjaxResponse(obj.select.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    var url = "ajax.cgi";
    var data = "action=retrieve-opp&proj-id=" + projID;

    xhr.open("POST",url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the request is asynchronous the function will return before your code in onreadestatechange fires.  You can switch to synchronous and get the value before the function returns:

```
function xhrRetrieve(projID) {
    var returnVal;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "ajax.cgi";
    var data = "action=retrieve-opp&proj-id=" + projID;

    //3rd param is false to switch to synchronous
    xhr.open("POST",url, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr.status == 200) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            return obj.select.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function xhrRetrieve doesn't have a return value.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: does not the `return obj.select.toString();` inside of `xhr.onreadystatechange` achieve this?

Comment: No, that will only happen when that XHR event gets fired.  If you want a blocking call, you will need to either set async=false when you call xhr.send; or better yet use an asynchronous solution like the snippet Bjorn posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions there. The inner function returns a value, but not the outer one.  The inner function is an event handler so the return value doesn't go anywhere.  Your XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, so you won't get a return value right away.  See this post for a more detailed explanation: [parameter "true" in xmlHttpRequest .open() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461958/parameter-true-in-xmlhttprequest-open-method/6462145#6462145)