# Only getting first line of file when loading into JavaScript because transfer-encoding: chunked

Tags: javascript, php, string, file, parsing

I have a file that looks like this

```
1 4
2 4
3 6
```

I load it into my code like this

```
var file = 'fileName';
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log(allText);
                setTimeout(otherFunction, 3000);
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
```

When I do

```
console.log(allText);
```

This is output:

```
1 4
//blank line
```

Why, and how do I fix it?

Edit: I see in the network tab that the downloaded file looks just like the console.log() output. However the file on the server looks as described at the top of this Question.

Edit: The problem is that

```
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

I need to either "unset transfer-encoding" or set the length of the file. But where and how do I do this? There is no PHP-file, the file is loaded directly from my server to JavaScript.

Comment: Curious ... Have you checked the network panel? Open the request you made and check that the file downloaded contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Is the `transfer-encoding`:`chunked`?

Comment: The `//more code` part is important as the `XmlHttpRequest` is asynchronous - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6462019/637889. Can you edit the question to show the whole function and exactly where the `console.log(allText)` exists please?

Comment: @andyb `readyState` is 4, means loaded compleatly.

Comment: how do i find out if transfer-encoding:chunked ?

Comment: you mean a length of the string? what is fw and avp? I don't know these terms. If you can give step by step instructions on how to retrieve this info then i'll retrieve them.

Comment: i mean the length of the whole file you are receiving in bytes (round about 11 bytes in your case). a fw is a firewall that blocks DoS-attacks or bufferoverflows into outer memory of network-software. a avp is a classic anti-virus-program that may cut additional data in tcp traffic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48867/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-user3324865)

Comment: i find that transfer-encoding is chunked, yes. How do I make it not so? install firewall or avp? if so, how do i do that?

Comment: my fault: i mean `A fw or a proxy or a avp will cut the rest off.`

Comment: Whilst it doesn't explain why `console.log(allText);` outputs `1 4`, my questions are: What is the `rawFile.status`? What URL is `fileName`? Are you using a web server or is the page that this JavaScript is on just a local file loaded by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

OP sais: `Chucked without length` in chat.

So i referee

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

"The size of each chunk is sent right before the chunk itself so that the receiver can tell when it has finished receiving data for that chunk. "

Comment: The provider of the webspace has Bugs in his software.