# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading

I'm getting an error in the console when loading a file:

> "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Even though there is an error, the data is still loading, although it takes 10 - 15 seconds. I would like to know the latency that is happening.

Code where the error originates:

```
mod.sendRequest=function(type, url, user, pass, data, headers, callback){
    var async=false;
    //check if the last argument is a function and treat it as callback;
    if(arguments[arguments.length-1]  instanceof Function){
        var async=true;
        callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];
    }
    //treat sencond last(if callback)/last(if no callback) argument as headers
    var headindex=arguments.length-((async || arguments[arguments.length-1] == null) ?2:1);
    //is it an array then it's headers
    if(arguments[headindex] instanceof Array){
        headers=arguments[headindex];
    }else{
        headers=[];
    }
    //are user AND password not specified then assume data as 3rd argument.
    if(typeof user == "string" && typeof pass == "string"){
        if(typeof data != "string"){
            data="";
        }
    }else if (typeof user == "string"){
        data = user;
        user=null;
        pass=null;
    }else{
        user=null;
        pass=null;
    }
    var xmlhttp= getHTTP();
    try{
        if(user!=null){
            xmlhttp.open(type, url, async, user, pass);
        }else{
            xmlhttp.open(type, url, async);
        }
    }catch(e){
        throw new mod.RequestOpenFailed(e);
    }
    //set headers
    for(var i=0;i< headers.length;i++){
        try{//opera 8b does not support setRequestHeader todo:
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(headers[i][0], headers[i][1]);    
        }catch(e){
        }
    }

    if(async){//set up a callback
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
                callback(xmlhttp);
                xmlhttp = null; //help IE with garbage collection
            }else if (xmlhttp.readyState==2){
                //status property should be available (MS IXMLHTTPRequest documentation) 
                //in Mozilla it is not if the request failed(server not reachable)
                //in IE it is not available at all ?!
                try{//see if it is mozilla otherwise don't care.
                    var isNetscape = netscape;
                    try{//if status is not available the request failed.
                        var s=xmlhttp.status;
                    }catch(e){//call the callback because Mozilla will not get to readystate 4
                        callback(xmlhttp);
                        xmlhttp = null;
                    }
                }catch(e){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    try{
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }catch(e){            
        if(async){
            callback(xmlhttp, e);
            xmlhttp=null;
        }else{
            throw new mod.SendFailed(e);
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: That means that all the AJAX (where A is in this case irrelevant) are made synchronously, it waits for one to be finished before executing another one, and so on... This is why there is more latency. This is due to the 'async' parameter in your codet that is passed to the open method of yours XMLHttpRequest instances. This link will help you to understand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461958/parameter-true-in-xmlhttprequest-open-method

Comment: It's not an error. It just a warning..!

Comment: yeah..i would like to know why the latency is occurring?